# Winform, If I start a new thread to do some time consuming task, do I need to 'close' the thread manually?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

There I declared a `timer` (the `period` value of this timer is 1 minute) when the form is initialized

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer_1m = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(timerElapsed_test), null, 0, _1min);
}
```

Every 60 seconds, I start a new thread to do something.

```
void timerElapsed_test(object sender) //timer period: 60 seconds
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Do));
    thread.Start(null);

}

void Do(object o)
{
    label1.Text = "triggerd at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); //assume this is a task needs to take a lot of time
    //Do I need to close this thread here? and how?
}
```

Do I need to `close` the thread manually? If yes, how?

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  Once the thread has exited (after it executes the last line) it will simply close and then be garbage collected automatically sometime in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Idle_Mind said, once the thread "exits" you are fine.

After a thread's routine has completed, garbage collection will handle it.